# plot turtles vs energy

Tags: plot, netlogo

Hello netlogo community

I have a simple model with 100 turtles and each one has a variable called energy.
How can I draw a graph that plots for each turtle in the world his energy
I mean:
x-axis each turtle 
y-axis energy associated to the turtle

Sorry I think is an easy question but I can figure out how to do it.
Ideally I would like an histogram like the following:

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI4PK.png)

Comment: You need to really try something yourself first, reading the manuals might help.

Comment: the netlogo histogram section: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/histogram.html

and the plotting section should help you out: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#plotting

Answer (score 4):

The NetLogo [`histogram`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#histogram) command won't allow you to plot each value individually, but it's not too hard to code it yourself.

Supposing you have a model with the following code:

```
turtles-own [ energy ]
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [ set energy random 100 ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

You can add a plot with a pen that is defined like this:

[image]

(Don't forget to set the pen mode to "Bar"!)

To get a plot like this:

[image]

Note that this uses the new NetLogo 6.0 anonymous procedure syntax. In NetLogo <= 5.3.1, you'd use `[ ask ? [ plot energy ] ]` instead of `[ [t] -> ask t [ plot energy ] ]`.

Also note that [`sort`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort) will sort your turtles by `who` number. Use [`sort-on`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort-on) if you prefer a different order.