# NetLogo: About how to monitor the status of various flags assigned to all turtles?

Tags: netlogo, monitor, behaviorspace

What should I do to monitor the status of various flags assigned to all turtles? As a possibility, can we think to use the Behavior Space? But it didn't go well. Can someone who know it well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to record the value of individual turtle variables using BehaviorSpace, check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406247/487946

But if you only want to monitor these values inside NetLogo while your model is running, you can use an output widget.

Here is a bit of example code:

```
turtles-own [ flag1? flag2? ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [
    set flag1? one-of [ true false ]
    set flag2? one-of [ true false ]
  ]
  update-output
end

to go
  ; flip a couple of random flags
  ask one-of turtles [ set flag1? not flag1? ]
  ask one-of turtles [ set flag2? not flag2? ]
  update-output
end

to update-output
  clear-output
  foreach sort turtles [ t ->
    ask t [ output-show (list flag1? flag2?) ]
  ]
end
```

And the kind of result it would give you:

[image: sample output]

You can, of course be as fancy as like with formatting the output. You get a bit of flickering, but it does the job.

Note that it is also possible to plot values for individual turtles using [dynamically created temporary plot pens](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#create-temporary-plot-pen). See this other answer for an example of something like that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41600187/487946